# Most Efficient way to filter a List that contains (almost) Duplicates in .Net

Tags: .net, algorithm, linq, sorting, grouping

I have a .Net backend that allows me to query items via the corresponding Client API by their .Id and .Revision property and even better, in bulk by providing a List of these combos.

However, each .Id may only appear *once* per query but the input *does* contain some entries with the same Ids multiple times, however with different .Revision values, e.g.:

```
.Id | .Revision
1   | 1
1   | 2
2   | 1 (unique .Id)
3   | 3
3   | 5
4   | 2 (unique .Id)
5   | 1 (unique .Id)
```

.. so basically the entries with .Id 1 and 3 cause problems and I am wondering what would the be most efficient way (= least amount of queries) to retrieve all combos.

Worst case runtime wise but easiest one to implement would  be to retrieve all combos one by one ignoring potential bulk/batching mechanisms, but even though this will logically return the correct set of items, it's obviously slow.

How would I get the largest set of unqiue .Id/.Revision combinations and combine the remaining multiple-.Id-ones together in the least amount of batches.. efficiently?

Comment: What's the underlying technology that linq is mapping to?

Comment: @CapTec there's no Linq Provider in place for querying the backend, the objects prior to the query are pure in-memory ones and of a custom type and basically the client API only takes int[] for both, .Id and .Revision value. So batching these in the least amount of batches happens in-memory, locally.

Comment: You could produce a tree out of the unique ids and under each branch have nodes for each revision. that way you can query your api as and when required for each node. (Think streaming your query in a manner of speaking). I may be misunderstanding your question though. I've done similar with XML so as to keep its memory footprint low in running memory, the same principal may work for querying an API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do this relatively easily with a few LINQ expressions in a loop.

For example, let's say you have an `Item` class like this:

```
public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Rev { get; set; }
}
```

And a list of those:  `List<Item> Items;` that you want to query in batches. Within a batch, no `Id` can occur more than once.

You can get the first query quite easily with `Distinct`:

```
var queryItems = Items.Distinct(new ItemIdComparer()).ToList();
```

And your comparer:

```
public class ItemIdComparer: IEqualityComparer<Item>
{
    public int Equals(Item x, Item y)
    {
        return x.Id == y.Id;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Item x)
    {
        return x.Id;
    }
}
```

But now you need the items that are left over. For that, you'll need an equality comparer that takes the revision into account, too:

```
public class ItemComparer: IEqualityComparer<Item>
{
    public int Equals(Item x, Item y)
    {
        return x.Id == y.Id && x.Rev == y.Rev;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Item x)
    {
        // not the best hash code, but should work okay.
        return x.Id ^ x.Rev;
    }
}
```

And to get the list of items that are in the original list but not in the distinct list, you call [Enumerable.Except](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb336390(v=vs.100).aspx):

```
var leftover = Items.Except(queryItems, new ItemComparer()).ToList();
```

If you put that in a loop, you can do that repeatedly until the `leftover` list is empty:

```
var workingItems = Items.ToList();
while (workingItems.Count > 0)
{
    var queryItems = workingItems.Distinct(new ItemIdComparer()).ToList();
    var leftover = workingItems.Except(queryItems, new ItemComparer()).ToList();
    DoQuery(queryItems);
    workingItems = leftover;
}
```

Using this algorithm, you could obtain the information for all of your items with just two queries. The first would get items 1.1, 2.1, 3.3, 4.2, and 5.1. The second query would get 1.2 and 3.5.

Comment: `GetHashCode` should presumably be `x.Id ^ x.Rev`, not `x.Id ^ y.Id`.

Answer (score 1):

Given a list of entries of this format:

```
public class Entry
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Version { get; set; }
}
```

How about grouping by Id, then projecting a new list of elements with the Id, Version and rank for each entry labelled as a batch number? The rank will be among all entries with the same Id. You can then group all entries with the same batch number and submit one batch at a time.

Here's my expression:

```
var entries = GenerateEntries();

    var result = entries
        .GroupBy(e => e.Id)
        //project new entries with a batch number 
        .SelectMany(g => g.Select((e, i) => new { Id = e.Id, Version = e.Version, Batch = i }))
        .GroupBy(e => e.Batch);
```

Comment: Although this would work, it would require 4 separate queries to get the information for the items in his example. It can be done in two.

Comment: I don't follow how this would lead to more queries to the database. Can you explain a bit? All of this logic is operating on his in memory list, before executing any queries.

Comment: I wrote a quick app to double check this and it leads to two batches. The first has 1.1, 2.1, 3.3, 4.2 and 5.1. The second batch has 1.2 and 3.5. Isn't that the same as your code?